# storing scores for several players in a <list>

Tags: c#, list

I'm making a program for keeping scores in a dart game where you can input x number of players and each player then gets to throw 3 arrows in the order they input their names and this repeats itself until someone reaches 501 points which ends the game.
The `list` for players seems to be working just fine but somehow I can't get the `list` for the arrows/score to work. I get no error in Visual Studio and I can run the program just fine, but if I try to print out the values in `arrowList` with a `foreach` loop nothing happens. As far as I can tell I've done the `arrowList` exactly as I did the `players` `list` which seems to work as intended, so why isn't the `arrowList` working??

I've been stuck on this task for my C# course for about a week now - I've found several questions here regarding a very similar task but I still can't get those suggestions to work with my code (and I don't want to just copy&paste their whole programs, after all I'm here to learn).
The code for my whole program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.PlayGame();
    }
}


class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
        //default  constructor that takes 0 arguments
    }


    int playernumber = 0;
    List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.Title = " Dartcounter 3000";
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Dartcounter 3000!");

        NumberOfPlayers();

        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            if (player.ToString() == "Dator")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Generating score for the NPC 'Dator'...");
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomThrow1 = random.Next(0, 60);
                int randomThrow2 = random.Next(0, 60);
                int randomThrow3 = random.Next(0, 60);
                Arrows arrows = new Arrows(randomThrow1, randomThrow2, randomThrow3);

                player.CalculatePoints();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's {0} turn to throw", player.ToString());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your score for the first arrow: ");
                int arrowOne = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Your second arrow: ");
                int arrowTwo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Your third arrow: ");
                int arrowThree = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Arrows arrows = new Arrows(arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree);
                Console.WriteLine(arrows.ToString());

                player.CalculatePoints();
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    // ------------ START of player methods in class Game ------------
    public void NumberOfPlayers()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of players: ");
        start:
        string playernumberinput = Console.ReadLine();
        int value;

        if (int.TryParse(playernumberinput, out  value))
        {
            playernumber = int.Parse(playernumberinput);
            AddPlayer();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not input a number. Please try again: ");
            goto start;
        }
    }


    public void AddPlayer()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < playernumber; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name of player {0}:", i + 1);
            players.Add(new Player(Console.ReadLine()));
        }
    }
    // ------------ END of player methods in class Game ------------
}





class Arrows
{
    public Arrows()
    {
        //default constructor that takes 0 arguements
    }

    public int roundScore;
    public Arrows(int roundScore)
    {
        this.roundScore = roundScore;
    }

    public int arrowOne { get; set; }
    public int arrowTwo { get; set; }
    public int arrowThree { get; set; }


    public Arrows(int Arrow1, int Arrow2, int Arrow3)
    {
        arrowOne = Arrow1;
        arrowTwo = Arrow2;
        arrowThree = Arrow3;

        Player player = new Player();
        player.AddArrows();
    }


    public int GetScore()
    {
            return arrowOne + arrowTwo + arrowThree;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (string.Format("You got a total of {0} this round!", GetScore()));
    }

}


class Player
{
    public Player()
    {
        //default  constructor that takes 0 arguments
    }

    public string Name;
    public List<Arrows> arrowList = new List<Arrows>();

    public Player(string Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public void AddArrows()
    {
        Arrows arrows = new Arrows();
        int roundScore = arrows.GetScore();
        arrowList.Add(new Arrows(roundScore));
    }

    public void CalculatePoints()
    {
        foreach (var arrow in arrowList)
        {
            //Calculation to sum up the entry's in arrowList to see if someone has reached 501 points
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (string.Format("{0}", Name));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't "learn" by using `goto`. You should be using a loop of some sort instead.

Comment: *Especially* when that goto is in another function. There are very *limited* valid uses for `goto` *within* a function, but you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Your `AddArrows` makes no sense. You create a new "empty" `Arrows`, call `GetScore`, then add a `new Arrows`?

Comment: There are no arrows in the game of darts.

Comment: You also don't need `playernumber`. At any point, you can get the amount of players by doing: `arrowList.Count()`. Like this, [these two can never run out of sync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Source_of_Truth). If you don't want to type all that to get that information, you could create a readonly property: `public int AmountOfPlayers { get { return arrowList.Count(); } }`. It is also considered good practice to avoid public fields (use private fields and public properties or Auto-Implemented Properties)

Comment: The code is *terrible* but the question is pretty clear, and he included the code. +1 for a pretty well written question. Unfortunately, the answer is to try re-writing this from scratch; perhaps with some guidance by an instructor or tutor (or even here, if the questions are well written enough).

Comment: Also, in C# it is conventional for public class members should be PascalCase, and method arguments should be camelCase. You have this backwards in your Arrows class properties and the Arrows constructor that takes 3 arrow ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up on this, I thought I'd walk through the process I use when developing and see if it helps. Plus, for some reason, this seemed like a fun project.

First, I copied/pasted the pseudo-code from my previous answer into a new console project, in the Main() method. Obviously a bunch of stuff was undefined, so then I started defining it so the code would compile.

The first thing that was undefined was `Player`, so I created an empty Player class:

```
public class Player { }
```

Next, the `GetPlayers()` method was undefined. This method will need to get all the players for the game and return them in a List, so I created the bare-bones method that returns a list of `Players`:

```
public static List<Player> GetPlayers()
{
    var players = new List<Player>();
    return players;
}
```

Next, the `AnnounceRound` method is undefined. I know this will simply announce that a new round is starting, and I decided to clear the console window at the start of each round as well:

```
public static void AnnounceRound(int roundNumber)
{
    Console.Clear();

    var announcement = string.Format("Beginning Round #{0}", roundNumber);
    Console.WriteLine(announcement);

    // The next line writes out a list of dashes that is the 
    // exact length of the announcement (like an underline)
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', announcement.Length));
}
```

Next, the `AnnouncePlayer` method is undefined. This will let everyone know who's turn it currently is:

```
private static void AnnouncePlayer(Player player)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}It's now {1}'s turn.{0}", Environment.NewLine, player.Name);
}
```

But when I wrote the code the way I WANTED to use it, there was a problem: The `Player` class does not have a `Name` property. So back to the `Player` class. I will make the property read only (by making the setter private), and take the name as a parameter to the constructor. This way we do not allow someone to create a `Player` and then change his name later (this is how I want to do it, but it's not necessary. If we later decide to make it read-write, we can easily change the setter to public):

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The next thing that needs definition is the `GetDarts` method on the player object. Now that I've had a day to sleep on it, I don't like this name. Methods that begin with `Get` typically return some object, and my intention for this method is that it represents the player walking up to the dart board and grabbing the darts. Internally I imagine it will simply update a counter that represents how many darts the player is holding. So I will rename it in the original pseudo-code and also in the implementation in 'Player':

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    private int dartsInHand;

    public void GrabDarts()
    {
        dartsInHand = 3;
    }
}
```

The next thing to implement is the 'HasUnthrownDarts' property. This is a bool that just represent whether the `Player` has any darts in hand or not.

```
public class Player
{
    . . .

    public bool HasUnthrownDarts { get { return dartsInHand > 0; } }
}
```

Next, we have the `ThrowDart` method. Now suddenly things get a little trickier. I noticed in your implementation, you let the human players enter their own score, and NPC players have a random-generated score. So this means a few things:

1. I have to have a property (or some other means) to differentiate between Human and NPC players
2. I have to do different things in this method depending on this property.

The simplest thing for now is to just create a bool property that defines the player type (and add this to the constructor with a default of `false`). If there were going to be more than two types of players, I would probably create an enum to define the types and a property on the `Player` object of that type. But for now, this will do:

```
public class Player
{
    . . .

    public bool IsNpc { get; private set; }

    public Player(string name, bool isNpc = false)
    {
        . . .

        IsNPC = isNpc;
    }
}
```

Now, implement the `ThrowDart` method. All this method will do is get a score between 0 and 60, add it to the player's score, and decrement the number of darts in the player's hand. After some further thought, I might also want to return the score generated in this method so a "round score" can be tallied if necessary, and I decided to output the dart number and points as well. As usual, I wrote the code that I WANTED to use, with the plan to implement it afterwards.

```
public int ThrowDart()
{
    if (dartsInHand < 1) 
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Player {0} has no darts to throw.", Name));
    }

    int dartScore;
    int thisDartNumber = (3 - dartsInHand) + 1;

    if (IsNpc)
    {
        // Get a random score for non-player characters
        dartScore = rnd.Next(0, 60);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} threw dart #{1} for {2} point{3}",
            Name, thisDartNumber, dartScore, dartScore == 1 ? "" : "s");
    }
    else
    {
        dartScore =
            ConsoleHelper.GetIntFromUser(string.Format(
                "{0}, please enter the score for dart #{1} (0-60): ",
                Name, thisDartNumber), "<Invalid score>", 
                (i) => i >= 0 && i <= 60);
    }

    Score += dartScore;
    dartsInHand--;
    return dartScore;
}
```

As I wrote this, I realized that I needed to get an integer from the user. This sounds simple, but it actually requires a bit of code to do the validation. The user could enter a non-integer string, in which case I'd have to ask them again. They could also enter a number that's outside of our bounds (0-60), in which case I would also have to ask them again. Because this code is semi-complex, and because I have a feeling we may need to get other integers from the user (we may need to ask how many NPC players they want to play against), I decided to create a new class called `ConsoleHelper` and add a method `GetIntFromUser` there. This method will simply get a string from the Console, convert it to an integer, apply some custom validation (if necessary), and return it. I've added some comments to help describe how it works as well:

```
public static class ConsoleHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an integer from the user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="prompt">A prompt to display to the user. Can be null.</param>
    /// <param name="errorMessage">An error message to display if 
    /// the user enters an invalid integer. Can be null</param>
    /// <param name="intValidator">A function to run which will validate 
    /// the integer. The integer  will be passed to it, and it should 
    /// return true if the integer is valid. Can be null</param>
    /// <returns>The integer entered by the user</returns>
    public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, string errorMessage, 
        Func<int, bool> intValidator)
    {
        int intEntered;

        while (true)
        {
            if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(input, out intEntered))
            {
                if (intValidator == null || intValidator(intEntered))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (errorMessage != null) Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
        }

        return intEntered;
    }
}
```

I also realized we also need to get random numbers for the NPC players. To do this, I created a private random property and set it in the constructor:

```
public class Player
{
    . . .       
    private readonly Random rnd;

    public Player(string name, bool isNpc = false)
    {
        . . .
        rnd = new Random();
    }
}
```

And I also am updating the imaginary Score property in this method, so let's implement that now, too:

```
public class Player
{
    . . .
    public int Score { get; private set; }
}
```

This also seems as good a time as any to take advantage of the fact that `ThrowDarts` returns the score for that dart number. For each player, for each round, I can give them a summary of how well they threw for that round:

```
. . .
var roundScore = 0;

while (p.HasUnthrownDarts)
{
    roundScore += p.ThrowDart();
    . . .
}

if (winner != null) break;

Console.WriteLine("{0} threw for {1} points this round.", p.Name, roundScore);
. . .
```

Another thing I decided to add was a 'MaxDarts' property to the Player. This allows me to store the number of darts in a single place, rather than have hard-coded '3's everywhere. So I added it to the `Player` class and updated the hard-coded values.

```
public class Player
{
    . . .
    public int MaxDarts { get; set; }

    public Player(string name, bool isNpc = false)
    {
        . . .
        MaxDarts = 3;
    }
}

public void GrabDarts()
{
    dartsInHand = MaxDarts;
}

public int ThrowDart()
{
    . . .
    int thisDartNumber = (MaxDarts - dartsInHand) + 1;
    . . .
}
```

So, now that everything is compiling, the last thing left to do is actually implement the `GetPlayers` method. In order to collect both human and computer player information from the user without writing duplicate code, I created a second `GetPlayers` method that takes in a boolean that says if it should be computer players or not. Then, the `GetPlayers()` method simply calls this overload twice - once with `false` and once with `true`. Here are both methods:

```
public static List<Player> GetPlayers()
{
    var players = GetPlayers(false);
    Console.WriteLine();
    players.AddRange(GetPlayers(true));            
    return players;
}

private static List<Player> GetPlayers(bool npcPlayers)
{
    var players = new List<Player>();
    var playerType = npcPlayers ? "NPC" : "human";

    int numberOfPlayers = ConsoleHelper.GetIntFromUser(
        string.Format("How many {0} players will be playing? ", playerType),
        "<Invalid number>", (x) => x >= 0);

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        string name;
        if (npcPlayers)
        {
            // Generate computer player names
            name = string.Format("ComputerPlayer{0}", i);
        }
        else
        {
            // Get human names from the user
            Console.Write("Enter the name for player #{0}: ", i);
            name = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        players.Add(new Player(name, npcPlayers));
    }

    return players;
}
```

One other thing I decided to do is, at the beginning of each round, display the current standings. This code would normally be a copy of the code at the end of the game (that shows the final scores). Because we should never write duplicated code if possible, I wrapped it in a method called `ShowScores`:

```
public static void ShowScores(string message, List<Player> players)
{
    if (message != null) Console.WriteLine(message);

    foreach (var p in players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" {0}: {1}", p.Name, p.Score);
    }
}
```

Then I added code to call this method at the beginning of each round, and at the end of the game:

```
private static void Main()
{
    . . .
            while (winner == null)
            {
                round++;
                AnnounceRound(round);
                ShowScores("The current standings are:", players);
                . . .
            }

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("We have a winner! Congratulations, {0}!!", winner.Name);
            ShowScores("The final scores are:", players);
            . . .
}
```

Now we're getting there. I decided to wrap the whole game inside another loop, in order to allow the users to play more than one game per session. To do enable this, I did a few things. First, added a `Reset()` method to the player class so their score would go back to zero:

```
public void Reset()
{
    Score = 0;
    dartsInHand = 0;
}
```

Then I wrapped the code in a loop, and reset the player's scores (if they already existed):

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Would you like to play a game of darts (y/n)? ");
    var playGame = Console.ReadKey();
    List<Player> players = null;

    while (playGame.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        if (players == null)
        {
            players = GetPlayers();
        }
        else
        {
            players.ForEach(p => p.Reset());
        }

        . . .

        Console.Write("{0}Would you like to play another game (y/n)? ", 
            Environment.NewLine);
        playGame = Console.ReadKey();
    }

    Console.Write("{0}Thanks for playing! Press any key to quit...", 
        Environment.NewLine);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Hope this trip through my brain helped in some way! :)

Comment: This is one of the longest answers I've read (not sure if thats good or bad). +1 for a excellently written post.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it was a waste of time, but it was fun for me. Hopefully it will help give an example of one way of approaching a problem like this.

Comment: I actually managed to make my program work with my (heavily modified) code earlier today and submitted it for my class. With that said though, I definitely appreciate your answer! I'm planning to go back and redo the program in a better way as soon as I finish my course since I realise I have to learn the foundations of C# (and OOP) better. I'll be using your answer as a guideline then and surely get a better understanding of what I'm doing and why on the way.

Answer (score 1):

That code needs... some work.

To answer your question though, you asked why the `foreach` doesn't print anything. I'll assume that you are referring to this one:

```
   foreach (var arrow in arrowList)
   {
      //Calculation to sum up the entry's in arrowList to see if someone has reached 501 points
   }
```

The only thing that adds to that collection is `AddArrows` which is weird, since you create arrows with the default constructor; call `GetScore` (which will always return 0, since you never initialized the arrows), then create a *new* `Arrows` object with that score.

Regardless, the only thing that calls *that* function is the *overloaded* constructor of `Arrows` which is even *weirder*; especially because you construct a new `Player` object here:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.AddArrows();
```

So your "new" arrows are scoped to that constructor; and then they fall out of scope and disappear.

You should be calling that function somewhere else; and about a million other things should be different (no `goto` statements for a start). Without re-writing your code for you (which you don't want; good for you!) its hard to say *how* to fix it. Honestly, the program is very small; I would just start over and maybe talk to my instructor on how to design it properly. Perhaps ask a few good questions here that relate to how to set this up.

Comment: I guess you are right. The biggest problem is that all the classes and methods in the program is stated in a UML that we are supposed to try to follow - and the teacher is not the one who designed the course or it's tasks, he just seems to be handling it now since the teacher who made it quit or something. So getting help from the instructor isn't that easy - hence I came here.. But I'll try remaking the program from scratch and see if I can make it with a better structure while still following the UML, my code HAS gotten messy from trying to implement solutions from other peoples questions

Comment: @Zoay The overall design is *fine* but I sincerely doubt there was a `Arrows`-<>`Player` relationship in that diagram (there certainly *shouldn't* have been), but you created one with the code I pointed out. Start with empty methods (following the design) and go from there (as you said). Given this question's quality, I imagine you could write a decent question during that process if you run into trouble. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's great you're learning programming, and I thought I'd take a minute to share one way to approach a problem like this that has helped me in the past.

### Know the Scenario and Key Pieces

When writing a simulation of real-world events and objects (which is pretty much what all programs do), I find it helpful to play out the scenario in my head first, figure out what the objects are, what their relevant properties and actions would be, and then try to write code to represent them. If the program is being written for someone else, this will come from an instructor or client in the real world.

### Write a Flow Chart

Before writing any code, create a flow chart for the scenario that the code is representing. For the example of a darts game (let's assume they're playing 301), I would picture how it would happen in real life. A number of friends get together, each picks up 3 darts, they decide on the order in which they'll throw, and then, one at a time, each player throws all their darts and adds up their score. This 'round' score is added to their total score. At the moment when a player throws a dart that gives them a total score of 501 or more, the game is over and that player is the winner.

### Create a UML diagram

Define the objects and how they will relate to each other. Define the relationships (one to many, many to many, is-a, has-a, etc.).

### Write pseudo-code

Write some sample code, using imagined objects to represent how you'd LIKE to use them. This should really give you a sense of which objects should have which properties and methods.

Here's one way I can imagine writing the code:

```
List<Player> players = GetPlayers();
Player winner = null;
int round = 0;

while (winner == null)
{
    round++;
    AnnounceRound(round);

    foreach(Player p in players)
    {
        AnnouncePlayer(p);

        p.GetDarts();

        while (p.HasUnthrownDarts)
        {
            p.ThrowDart();

            if (p.Score >= 501)
            {
                winner = p;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (winner != null) break;
     }
}

Console.WriteLine("We have a winner! Congratulations, {0}!!", winner.Name);

Console.WriteLine("The final scores are:");

foreach(Player p in players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Score))
{
    Console.WriteLine(" {0}: {1}", p.Name, p.Score);
}
```

Now you have to define how the 'GetPlayers()' method will work using similar techniques, how the ThrowDart() method will update the player's score and his 'HasUnthrownDarts' property (and potentially output the resulting score of the specific throw), and what the AnnounceRound() and AnnouncePlayer() methods will output to the screen.

Hope that helps.

Comment: *Sigh* It's sad that people are taught programming now by starting at the most abstract level (UML) and working their way down. If you're going to build a skyscraper a pretty concept painting is great, but without a concrete understanding of foundations, structural integrity, plumbing, etc. your shiny new fountain is not going to have a lobby to sit in. It's not the OP's fault, it's the instructor for giving the student an assignment with lists and classes before they understand basic loop constructs.